# Establishing competing memory limits for pushdown automata

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, context-free, proofs

<strike>Let $L$ be the language of all even-length strings whose first half is a palindrome.</strike>

Let $L$ be the language of all even length strings whose first half is imbalanced—with an unequal number of $\mathtt{a}$'s and $\mathtt{b}$'s. I believe $L$ is not context-free; the intuition is that the equipment of a PDA can either be used to keep both halves of the string the same length, or to construct complex internal structure like a palindrome or an imbalanced string, but not both simultaneously.

I would like to formalize this intuition as a general conjecture, beyond this particular example $L$. I suggest that, letting $A\bowtie B$ denote the language $\{xy : x\in A,\;y\in B,\; |x|=|y|\}$,

> **Conjecture**: $A\bowtie \Sigma^*$ is context free if and only if $A$ is regular.

This conjecture would then establish that $L\equiv \mathsf{imbalanced}\bowtie \Sigma^*$ isn't context-free.  One direction $(\Leftarrow)$ is easy, using regular grammars. But I wonder if anyone knows or can see a proof of the other direction?

**Is a proof of this statement already well known or easily constructible?**

---

Maybe it would be easier to prove this more broadly:

> **Conjecture**: If $A\bowtie B$ is context free and  $A$ and $B$ have the same word sizes $\{|x| : x\in A\} = \{|y| : y \in B\}$, then  $A$ and $B$ are regular.

So far I have tried arguing about the derivation tree for $A\bowtie \Sigma^*$, considering cases of which parentheses are allowed on which halves of the string in the Chomsky Schuetzenberger theorem, limiting to the case where $A$ and $\Sigma^*$ have different(-colored) alphabets, and similar. I have proved it for the case where the alphabets of $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (e.g. color-coded), by arguing about the cases of colors of strings that the nonterminals of a grammar for $A\bowtie B$ can produce in CNF.

Edit: Having looked at generating functions, I know that if $A(x)$ is the generating function for strings of each length $n$ in $A$, then $A(2x^2)$ is the generating function for $A\bowtie \Sigma^*$, and I know that regular grammars correspond to rational generating functions, unambiguous context-free grammars have algebraic generating functions, and $\bowtie$ corresponds to the Hadamard product, which has certain closure properties relative to rational and algebraic functions—but since I don't know a characterization of what kind of context-free languages $A\bowtie B$ can be, I don't see what to uncover next.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but it seems to me that the first language can be proven not CFL using the pumping lemma. Take the words $s=uvwxy=a^Nba^Nb^{2N+1}$. Since $|vwx|\leq N$. By pumping, the palindrome is always destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right.  I will edit the question with a better example, and hopefully still be able to prove the theorem.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151275/755

Comment: @D.W. Useful reference to show that the conjecture for $A\bowtie B$ doesn't hold for arbitrary $B$. I wonder if there's a way to apply that reasoning to the original conjecture about $A\bowtie \Sigma^*$.

Comment: On alphabet $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, isn't the language $\{0^n 1 (0|1)^{3n+1} | n > 0\}$ context-free, for the same reason that $\{0^n 1^{3n} | n > 0\}$ from the CS.SE question is? If so, doesn't this refute your claim because $A = \{0^n 1 (0|1)^n | n > 0\}$ is context-free but not regular?

Comment: @a3nm. Yes, that refutes the claim!  The language is context free but its half language is not regular. Thanks very much.

Comment: @user326210 sure! I just posted this as an answer to the question to clarify that the problem is settled.

Comment: By the way $L$ (first half unbalanced) is context free: just scan the string adding $a$s and subtracting $b$s to/from the stack (or the opposite), and at each position $i$, if the stack is not empty non-deterministically jump to a state that checks that $i$ is exactly half the length of the string (if it is accept, otherwise reject). So this is another proof that the conjecture is false :-)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is inspired by [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151275/755). The conjecture is false, for the following reason. Consider the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, and the language $A=\{0^n1(0|1)^n|n>0\}$. This language is context-free but not regular.

Now, $A \bowtie \Sigma^*$ is the language $\{0^n 1 (0|1)^{3n+1}|n>0\}$. This language is context-free, for the same reason as the language $\{0^n 1^{3n}|n>0\}$ from the question mentioned before.

Thus, this refutes the conjecture.